# Stub the same endpoint twice in cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I want to stub the same API endpoint twice, so the second call returns different response than the first one. Here is snippet how I imagine this would work:

```
cy.route('POST', 'access-tokens', '@loginFailResponse', {status: 401}).as('loginFail')
cy.route('POST', 'access-tokens', '@loginSuccessResponse').as('loginSuccess')
```

The first time I try to login it denies access, I change form inputs and then it should let me in.

I tried to wrap second `cy.route(...)` definition as  callback function to first output but cypress denies calling `cy.anything` in promises. Like in example below

```
cy.route('POST', 'access-tokens', '@loginFailResponse', {status: 401, onResponse: () => {
      cy.fixture('login_screen/login_success_response.json').as('loginSuccessResponse')
      cy.route('POST', 'access-tokens', '@loginSuccessResponse').as('loginSuccess')}
}}).as('loginFail')
```

here is my test case:

```
cy.route('POST', 'access-tokens', '@loginFailResponse', {status: 401}).as('loginFail')
cy.route('POST', 'access-tokens', '@loginSuccessResponse').as('loginSuccess')
cy.get("form input[type='email']").type("bad@email.com")
cy.get("form input[type='password']").type("Bad password")
// this should fail
cy.get("form").submit()
cy.get("form input[type='password']").type("g00d@password.com")
// this should let me in
cy.get("form").submit()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everytime you define `.route('VERB', '/endpoint', ...)` it overrides your previous definition. The simplest solution would be to override this endpoint after you finish your first call

This test will work for you, Filip.

```
cy.route('POST', 'access-tokens', '@loginFailResponse', {status: 401}).as('loginFail')
cy.get("form input[type='email']").type("bad@email.com")
cy.get("form input[type='password']").type("Bad password")
// this should fail
cy.get("form").submit()
cy.route('POST', 'access-tokens', '@loginSuccessResponse').as('loginSuccess')
cy.get("form input[type='password']").type("g00d@password.com")
// this should let me in
cy.get("form").submit()
```